# What are the tools that allow Deployment of Docker images?

Tags: docker, deployment, rancher

Let's consider a Continuous Integration & Delivery pipeline that builds and push a Docker image to a Docker registry. I'd like to be able to:

- Manually deploy this Docker image, on demand, providing a configuration
- Automate the deployment of this Docker image whenever it changes

Most of the tools that I found are based on the re-build of a Git tag whenever we need to deploy it which is a waste of resources - a matter that is critical considering the climate change.

What are the tools that can be used to deploy Docker images, both manually and automatically? Would Rancher covers the requirements?

Comment: Not sure what you are looking for exactly, but here is the tool I'm working on - https://worklifenotes.com/2023/05/02/reliza-cd-tutorial-deploying-on-kubernetes/

P.s. Rebuilding images to deploy is certainly an anti-pattern, most people agree on that.